# Source for parents having ruach hakodesh when naming a child?

Tags: sources-mekorot, names, ruach-hakodesh

I remember hearing that parents have Ruach Hakodesh when choosing a name for their child.

What's the source for this idea? And do the sources discuss what this actually means? (If a parent gives a non-jewish name, does that still come with ruach hakodesh?)

Comment: What about when choosing a Mi Yodeya username? #PTIJ

Comment: @DoubleAA your comment made me think of another question: does a baal teshuva have ruach hakodesh when choosing a name for himself in real life.

Comment: What if the parents each have a different name they want to name the child?

Comment: @dude that's a very interesting point!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There appear to be multiple sources for this, and I don't want to "hog" things, here. One (or two) source(s) from [here](http://www.aish.com/tp/i/m/48909437.html):

> The Ari taught that Jewish parents are imbued with Ruach Hakodesh, a
>   spark of the "Holy Spirit," when they name their children. The name
>   they select is invariably the true description of the neshama, or
>   spiritual essence of their child.
>
> The Talmud expresses this same concept in terms of character (Yuma,
>   83b); a Jew's name accurately reflects his or her essential character.
>   The clear implication; when parents name their child, they are given a
>   prophetic glimpse of their child's neshama, or "spiritual essence".

The original source for the teaching of the Ari is [here](https://he.m.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%A2%D7%A8_%D7%94%D7%92%D7%9C%D7%92%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%94%D7%A7%D7%93%D7%9E%D7%94_%D7%9B%D7%92) and reads:

> ונמצא כי כאשר נולד האדם, וקוראים לו אביו ואמו שם אחד העולה בדעתם, אינו באקראי ובהזדמן, כי אם הקב"ה משים בפיו השם ההוא המוכרח אל הנשמה ההיא, כמש"ה אשר שם שמות בארץ

Regarding non-Jewish names, Yiddish names, "new" names, etc., see [this article](https://www.bvkkosher.com/naming---halacha-and-hashkafa), as there are various halachic opinions for each scenario.

Regardless of the halachic opinions mentioned some things to consider:

- Esther and Rus and non-Jewish names. They are used frequently.
- The Talmud has numerous Aramaic, Greek and other "weird" names, etc. - Yanai, Unkelos, Sa'adia, Mar ...
- Likewise, Yiddish names abound - Zissel, Shainah, Mendel, etc.

Comment: +1 this answers the first part of the question. Any comment on the second part? (Maybe i should edit it out and ask separately?)

Comment: Offhand, I think that the Ruach Hakodesh is there, regardless of the type of name that they choose. Every name reflects the child's character. It's questionable, however, if they name someone after a *rasha*, perhaps. I'll see if I can find another article that discusses the types of names. I don't think you need to separate the 2nd part into another question, though.

Comment: This argument is especially amusing for Ashkenazi "animal" names :-D

Comment: A rabbi in Chabad told me that the English name my parents chose for me was likewise influenced by Ruach Hakodesh, and that it would therefore be appropriate to add it to my Hebrew name.

Comment: @Kazibácsi I think naming people after animals is the least of the problem. Almost everyone of the 12 *shevatim* were compared to at least one animal each. Whenever I have a friend, Ari in my home, and he rises, I remind him of the first statement in *Shulchan Aruch* - *Yakum Ke'Ari*.

Comment: The linked article doesn't source the Arizal quote. [This](https://he.m.wikisource.org/wiki/שער_הגלגולים_הקדמה_כג) is the source: "ונמצא כי כאשר נולד האדם, וקוראים לו אביו ואמו שם אחד העולה בדעתם, אינו באקראי ובהזדמן, כי אם הקב"ה משים בפיו השם ההוא המוכרח אל הנשמה ההיא, כמש"ה אשר שם שמות בארץ"

Comment: OTOH, this kabbalistic tradition is somewhat of a contradistinction to the passage from Chazal ([Midrash, Gen. Rabbah](https://www.sefaria.org/Bereishit_Rabbah.37.7?vhe=Daat_Bereshit_Rabbah&with=all&lang=bi)): "רַבָּן שִׁמְעוֹן בֶּן גַּמְלִיאֵל אוֹמֵר הָרִאשׁוֹנִים עַל יְדֵי שֶׁהָיוּ מִשְׁתַּמְּשִׁין בְּרוּחַ הַקֹּדֶשׁ, הָיוּ מוֹצִיאִין לְשֵׁם הַמְאֹרָע, אֲבָל אָנוּ שֶׁאֵין אָנוּ מִשְׁתַּמְּשִׁין בְּרוּחַ הַקֹּדֶשׁ אָנוּ מוֹצִיאִין לְשֵׁם אֲבוֹתֵינוּ".

Comment: @Oliver I think the 1st comment should be copied into my answer. You might want to make the second comment your own answer.

Comment: @DanF It's fine for the lion of Yehudah and the deer of Naftali, but what about Dov and Fishl for example? :-)

Comment: @Kazibácsi Dov is mentioned numerous times in Tanac"h. David probably would not have received Sha'ul's permission to kill Goliat unless he had killed a *dov* beforehand (unless he was making up the story.) I can't comment about *Fishel*. But as it's my middle name, I can say that I like it, as well as the uncle I'm named after, zt"l.

Comment: @Oliver Friendly reminder about moving part of your comment to a separate answer. I also think that the linked article in my answer refers to the various attitudes of different *rabbanim* and I think it partially cites that Midrash.

Comment: @DanF Kind of you; I'll attempt to make an edit. Re. the 2nd half, I anticipate critics commenting that -as is- doesn't suffice for an answer per the site's rules and I honestly I have no time to elaborate on it to make it into a fuller, more robust answer. Re. *Fishel*, though it's not a bilical word, *dag* is and IMO it's not any worse than Yehuda, Gur Aryeh, Z'ev etc.

Comment: @Kazibácsi fish don't have ayin hara...