# PTIJ: Is there Ruach HaKodesh when naming your Mi Yodeya username?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

[We know](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/91484/) that parents are given a special Ruach HaKodesh when naming their child.

Since a Mi Yodeya user is considered a Jewish person, as evidenced by their [potentially being obligated in Lo Yilbash](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/80851/), is there a special Ruach HaKodesh given when naming one's user? Is it limited to Mi Yodeya, or does it extend to other websites as well?

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: [H/t DoubleAA for the idea](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/91484/source-for-parents-having-ruach-hakodesh-when-naming-a-child#comment296918_91484)

Comment: What if your username _is_ your name in real life? I mean, take a look at mine, or yours...

Comment: @ezra What's your point? Maybe the Ruach HaKodesh in such cases is that one *doesn't* come up with a unique username.

Comment: ....לא ברוח השם

Answer (score 1):

On all websites one must rely on Ruach HaKodesh, since we are in Galus, as it says in Zohar ([3:266a](https://www.sefaria.org/Zohar.3.266a.6)):

> בְּכָל אֲתָר דְּאִיהוּ סָתִים, רוּחַ הַקֹּדֶשׁ אַמָרוֹ עָלַיְיהוּ דְּיִשְׂרָאֵל בְּגָלוּתָא.
>
> On all websites it is closed, [but] Ruach HaKosdesh informs them since Israel is in exile.

1:238b

> בְּכָל אֲתַר לְדָוִד סְתָם, רוּח הַקֹּדֶשׁ אֲמָרוֹ
>
> Any website for Dovid was closed - Ruach HaKodesh informed him.

This divine wisdom, however, will not allow sacred names to be desecrated. (ibid. 3:51b):

> שְׁמָא קַדִּישָׁא לָא שַׁרְיָא בַּאֲתַר מִסְאֲבָא.
>
> A holy username does not fall on inappropriate websites.